# Using Google Earth API inside iPad app's

Tags: ipad, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, iphone

I need to create an iPad application that uses Google Earth at its core.  So Basically when the app opens it will need to run Google Earth.

Then I would need to add additional features tailored to our business such as photos of our different hotels and offers and different icons and various features.

1. Is this at all possible and how difficult would it be for a C# developer do you think?
2. Do you know of any other similar app's besides Google Earth?

Comment: Must you use Google Earth instead of just Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Google Earth and the Google Earth Plug-in are, to date, not supported on the iPad. There is a  Google Earth iPhone application that works on the iPad but this has no public api. You can however load custom Kml into the application and that may be enough for your needs.

I don't know of any other solutions.